# Phaser set draggable for group

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

so I have a group of tiles, which I would like to make draggable, But i've seen in other answers that moving a group or child isn't possible, so what are the alternatives to that, other that just making a different variable for each tile.

UPDATE

So i've tried making a container, and i have no console errors, but i also cannot drag it.

code

```js
this.grass = this.add.image(200, 100, "tileTexture", 0);
    this.dirt = this.add.image(200, 116, "tileTexture", 1);
    
    this.container = this.add.container(0, 0, [ this.grass, this.dirt ]);
    this.container.setSize(this.grass.width,(this.grass.height*2))
    this.container.setInteractive();
    this.input.setDraggable(this.container);

    this.input.on("drag", function (pointer, gameObject, dragX, dragY) {
      gameObject.x = dragX;
      gameObject.y = dragY;
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the problem has to do with how you are creating the container and the children.

When you create the childeren you are positioning "far" away from the contatiner origin. And the only area that is draggable is from the contatiner origin to the size you defined.

**Here a short sketch, showcasing the issue:**

[image: sketch]

so if you want to be able to click the tiles and drag them you would have to something like this:

```
// set the container where you want the tiles to be
this.container = this.add.container(200, 100, [ this.grass, this.dirt ]);

// set the tiles relative to to container origin
this.grass = this.add.image(0, 0, "tileTexture", 0);
this.dirt = this.add.image(0, 16, "tileTexture", 1);


this.container.setSize(this.grass.width,(this.grass.height*2))
```

> **From the documentation:**  *...The position of the Game Object automatically becomes relative to the position of the Container. ...* for more details check ([link to documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.Container.html))